# Spring Rest @HandleAfterCreate doesn't fire

Tags: java, spring, rest

I've an handler class annotated with [@RepositoryEventHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryEventHandler.html) and a method annotated with [@HandleAfterCreate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/HandleAfterCreate.html), like following:

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(Test.class)
public class PropositionEventHandler {
    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void handleAfterCreate(final Proposition proposition) {
        System.out.println("Created");
    }
}
```

And a [@RepositoryRestResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html) like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "tests", path = "tests")
@CrossOrigin
public interface TestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Test, Long> {

}
```

So, when I send a json through `Postman` to my rest api, `Spring` inserts the record correctly into the database, but the event `HandleAfterCreate` never fires.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: How is your directory structured?  is this class `PropositionEventHandler` scanned during start up? Do you have any componentscan specified?

Comment: Many congratulations... the packages was renamed so the PropositionEventHandler is left in another package. That's the problem, now it works. Thanks.

Comment: this is annotation deprecated.

Comment: Which one?  If you are talking about the RepositoryEventHandler class, the only deprecated thing is the optional parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change type of your first parameter in method, because in your implementation it handles events from `Proposition` repository. Spring uses first parameter to determine which event this handler can handle.

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler
public class PropositionEventHandler {
    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void handleAfterCreate(final Test proposition) {
        System.out.println("Created");
    }
}
```